Why does my PDF from Overleaf look good in Preview but bad in Adobe?
When I write documents in Overleaf, I can see a preview of the document in the right window. I like how the document looks in Overleaf's preview; fortunately, this is also how it looks when I download the PDF and open it using Preview on my Mac.
Unfortunately, the documents look worse if I open them using Adobe Acrobat or Google Chrome’s PDF viewer. More specifically, the text becomes fainter, thinner and stretched. This problem seems to persist when I upload the documents onto my website.
How do I ensure that the documents always look as they do when I open them on Preview?
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{April 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Some text

\end{document}

Here is a screenshot of how it looks on Preview (good):

Here is a screenshot of how it looks on Adobe (bad):

As I mentioned, I am asking about this because I upload these documents onto my website and want to make sure (if possible) that anyone who views the document on my website sees the 'good' version.
N.B. I tried \usepackage{embedfile} at ChatGPT's suggestion but this didn't resolve the issue.

You can't (ensure that they always look the same). Many PDF viewers incorporate anti aliasing and other methods to make PDF output look "nicer" on screen; these are sometimes technically against the PDF spec. As the issue boils down to how different PDF viewers choose to convert the information in the PDF file to a presentation of the document on screen, there's nothing you can do.

@WillieWong Thanks for the information. Even if I can't ensure that they always look the same, is there a way to make them look like they do in Preview when viewed using Chrome's PDF viewer?

Sounds to me like a request you should forward to Adobe.

In addition to the considerations explained by Willie Wong above, even people using the same PDF viewer may get different results if they’re on different operating systems or different versions of an operating system and/or have configured their PDF viewer and/or their windowing software differently.

you could try avoiding cm which is a tricky font, try \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}

The rendering used on Apple devices is different than Windows or Linux. Text in general looks thicker on mac os. As others have commented, it also depends on the pdf reader. If you want thicker Computer Modern, you can take a look at the New Computer Modern (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern) or the Mlmodern (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mlmodern) fonts.

Thanks for the suggestions! I guess changing the font is the way to go.
